# How did Kylo Ren know how to obtain Darth Vader's helmet/skull?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, darth-vader, kylo-ren, return-of-the-jedi

In *Episode VII: The Force Awakens* we see a scene with Kylo Ren meditating in the presence of Darth Vader's helmet.

Given that in Episode VI Luke burns Darth Vader's body on the moon of Endor, I think it would be safe to say that was Darth Vader's resting place.

So how did Kylo Ren end up with part of Darth Vader? Did he travel to the moon of Endor to specifically get a piece of Darth Vader?

This question is not how any part of Darth Vader survived Return of the Jedi but **how Kylo Ren would know how to find the helmet**.

Comment: Found it in the dumpster where the Ewoks toss out all their scraps and empty food containers.

Comment: High bidder on Space eBay.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - The second part of the question is answerable and not a dupe  (although saying "his dad probably told him a story and mentioned the name of the planet" is terribly mundane).

Comment: Well, the other question does suggest there was a trade in Darth Vader memorabilia. Then again, some degree of duplication isn't so bad.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - The answer to the first part is already covered. **We don't know.**

Comment: I think it's far more likely Luke took it with him immediately after the funeral.

Comment: @David H, why would Luke take any part of Vader? Is there a cannon reason?

Comment: As per the last paragraph, this isn't a dupe as the answer on the target doesn't address the question and isn't intended to.

Comment: the question assumes he was the one who found it and not the First Order prior to Ren's joining (ie - it may have been given to him without his knowing about it prior) - the new canon book "Bloodlines" makes this a possibility. Future works - it is unanswerable at this time

Comment: The answer is - **Bad Writing** the whole of *Force Awakens* is full if things like this that are not explained and are giant plot holes just... EVERYWERE!!!

Comment: Chat room located here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41067/darth-vader-discussion

Comment: @DarthVader I imagine Luke rejoining the festivities after the funeral, taking one look at that Ewok who made drum set out of storm trooper helms, and thinking "I just can't let Dad's favorite helmet end up like that too."

Comment: I heard this was covered in a short story so it might make sense to reopen the question.

Comment: @MarkRogers where is this short story? "I heard" is not evidence. Until you are certain you have a canon answer it should be left closed.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Alright take it easy: *"According to Star Wars Minute, the Kylo Ren Darth Vader helmet explanation is buried in Delilah S. Dawson‘s short story [**The Perfect Weapon**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Perfect_Weapon), published in November as one of those **“Journey to The Force Awakens”** tie-ins... "* from [‘Star Wars: The Force Awakens’: Is This How Kylo Ren Got Darth Vader’s Helmet?](http://www.slashfilm.com/kylo-ren-darth-vader-helmet/).  "Journey to the force Awakens is canon, and perhaps the short story is too (probably).

Comment: @MarkRogers you should have lead with this...

Comment: Ha, fair enough.  I was just being lazy because I just saw the reference in the short text for a google search, and figured it must be more well known by now, but perhaps its not cannon.  Its hard to know for sure where that line is.

Comment: The answer is "We don't know". But my thinking is that SOMEONE would have gathered Vader's remains, and maybe squirreled them away to sell on space-EBay. Kylo Ren won the bid.

Comment: A scrapped version of the opening crawl of The Last Jedi was rumored to have mentioned that it was a spare helmet he had in his wardrobe on Mustafar. ;)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/how-did-darth-vaders-helmet-survive-return-of-the-jedi

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Luke was the only one present when he cremated his father on the pyre, on Endor. So, Kylo found out from Luke prior to the events of The Force Awakens. It follows that Kylo went to Endor and retrieved Vader's helmet.

Comment: It's also possible that Luke kept it and Kylo stole it when he left.

Comment: I don't feel based on Luke's characterisation and what we know of Jedi beliefs that he would keep a relic like that? The way bodies of powerful Jedi dissolve always made me feel like the body was not a big part of the Jedi view of death etc? This answer is definitely the most plausible; we don't know anything about Kylo Ren's time with Luke, only that they spent a lot of time together and that Luke would have attempted to mentor him. Luke may not even have explicitly told him that the remains were on the moon of Endor, only that Vader wasn't left on the Death Star, the rest could be inferred

Comment: More's the point, Luke wasn't alone on Endor. I think we can reasonably assume that multiple people knew about the cremation including Luke's sister and Han Solo (e.g. Kylo's mum and dad).

Comment: @Austin - It's also possible that smuggler Han Solo unburied it years later so that he could sell it for cash.

Comment: Is there a source for this?